# Decrease the number of lines of code needed to create a list and verify one value

Tags: python

What can I do to reduce the number of steps until I get to the final code result?
Is it possible or is this the way with the least number of lines of code?

```
import requests
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
    }
url = f'https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/9567795/graph'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
goal_minute = 88
graphs = response['graphPoints']
graph_minutes = graphs[-5:]
minutes_list = []
for minute in graph_minutes:
    minutes_list.append(minute["minute"])
if goal_minute in minutes_list:
    print('Ok')
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Lines of code is typically not a useful metric**. Many other characteristics are more
important: correctness, robustness, readability, simplicity, and so forth. But even if
we focus narrowly on code size, number of lines if usually the wrong way to
think about it. Less code can be beneficial sometimes: if done well, for
example, less code is easier to read than more code. But it's quite possible to
have both more lines and less code (if the lines are short). Many short lines,
especially if well organized into meaningful groups prefaced by substantive
comments, are often easier to read and understand than a small number of long,
dense lines of code.

**You might need more code**. HTTP requests can fail. You should probably be
writing code to handle that scenario.

```
try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
except Exception as e:
    # Adjust after you decide how you want to respond to failure.
    print(e)
    quit()
```

**The primary opportunity for brevity**. You can collect the needed minutes
in less code by dropping intermediate variables and using a comprehension. Although it could be written in a single
line, why not help your reader a bit by laying it out nicely? Whitespace
imposes no tax on the reader: be generous with it.

```
minutes = [
    d['minute']
    for d in response['graphPoints'][-5:]
]
```

Comment: Also, consider using a set instead of a list if there might be a large number of minutes and many goal_minutes need to be checked

Comment: Hi @TamoghnaChowdhury Could you show us this tip in an answer and in code form so that I and others can understand how this improvement can and should be implemented? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @j.g. has already incorporated my suggestion into their answer.

Answer (score 3):

In general, high line count is at most a code smell (i.e. a *possible hint* one should refactor). But if it is, that's because more declarative code might be clearer.

In this case, I want to discuss an unrelated issue we should address in such an attempt. Creating your list in the first place is unnecessarily eager. Your last `if` statement's boolean can be changed to `any(minute['minute'] == goal_minute for minute in response['graphPoints'][-5:])`. (I've still "wasted" a line making `goal_minute`, because  `== 88` isn't as clear in its significance.)

In a comment under @FMc's answer, @TamoghnaChowdhury suggested making a set instead of a list, which makes membership checking quicker. The smallest change to your original code to achieve this is using `minutes_set = set()` (then `append` becomes `add`); if you want something declarative instead of imperative, which reduces line count as you originally suggested, you can try `goal_minute in {minute['minute'] for minute in response['graphPoints'][-5:]}`. But *I don't recommend this*, because even a set is still eager, i.e. it takes up space we don't need. Admittedly, `response['graphPoints']` has to be eager no matter what, but it's good to get into the habit of passing a generator to `any`. (If nothing else, it can be even faster if an example is found early.)

Comment: Good catch that it doesn't need to be an eager collection! If they need it again, though... Also, if there are multiple goal minutes, they can all be in a set and minute == goal_minute will become minute in goal_minutes

Comment: Why don't you just pass a generator to `in`? Then it would be lazy as well.

Comment: @KellyBundy Maybe I'm missing something. How can I replace `response['graphPoints'][-5:]` with something lazy?

Comment: I guess you could make the `[-5:]` lazy with for example islice on reversed or with a range from -5 to -1. But what I meant is `goal_minute in (minute['minute'] for minute in response['graphPoints'][-5:])`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I suppose the conceptual advantage of `any` is it doesn't require us to characterize the condition in terms of such a collection. But this is the kind of decision which, in a large codebase, matters less than consistency with the rest of it.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean it's better than the any-solution, just saying because you complained about the set so I thought "Well then don't use a set" :-). Though now that I think about it, I imagine the in-solution could be a bit faster than the any-solution if there are many values to go through.